# How to setup rabbitmq service with Github Actions?

Tags: rabbitmq, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to set up Github Actions CI for an app that is using RabbitMQ.

RabbitMQ container is started using:

```
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
```

But now I need to configure it with smth like `rabbitmqctl add_user user password`.

How can it be done? Should I be using rabbitmq container here at all?

Answer (score 4):

As this is using [the rabbitmq Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq), you can configure user credentials by passing in the `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER` and `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS` environment variables.

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq
  env:
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: craiga
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: security_is_important
  ports:
    - 5672:5672
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's a bit out of date. In RabbitMQ 3.9, configuration with environment variables was removed from the docker container.

In my case, I dealt with this by locking in to RabbitMQ 3.8, with `image: rabbitmq:3.8`. It would maybe be better to use a configuration file, but that could be complex.

Comment: @spencernelson I'm using env variables to configure rabbitmq as of version 3:11. Did they re-add the ability to do configurations?

Answer (score 4):

If you have trouble connecting to RabbitMQ, try with a dynamic port.

Use this:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3.8
        env:
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
        ports:
          - 5672

    steps:
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py test
      env:
        RABBITMQ_HOST: 127.0.0.1
        RABBITMQ_PORT: ${{ job.services.rabbitmq.ports['5672'] }}
```